# Flow control and Failed: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db".... Error

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I am running into some odd behavior with one of my celery tasks.

```
def run_single_test(test_name_or_decorator):
    # get dict of test names, test paths
    test_dict = get_single_test_names()

    # check to see if test is in the dict
    if test_name_or_decorator not in test_dict:
        return 'The requested test could not be found.'

    for test_name, test_path in test_dict.items():
        # if test name is valid run associated test
        if test_name == test_name_or_decorator:
            pytest.main(['-p', 'no:django','--json-report', test_path])
            report = return_test_result_json('.report.json')
            report_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
            test_run_data = TestResults.objects.create(name=report_id, data=report)

    return 'this is your test report: {}'.format(get_report(test_run_data.id))
```

This task will execute the pytest.main() command and run a test however when it goes to insert the .report.json into the Db with .create() I get the following error:

```
Failed: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it.
```

Now if I take all the functionality within the `for test_name....` block simplify things and move it into its own function everything works:

```
def run_single_test_path():

    test_path = 'test_folder/test_file.py::TestClass::specific_test_name'
    pytest.main(['-p', 'no:django','--json-report', test_path])
    report = return_test_result_json('.report.json')
    report_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    test_run_data = TestResults.objects.create(name=report_id, data=report)
    return 'this is your test report: {}'.format(get_report(test_run_data.id))
```

I get the expected return:

```
"this is your test report: {'created': datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 27, 15, 51, 59, 297991, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'summary': {'total': 1, 'passed': 1}, 'exitcode': 0}"
```

This behavior is not happening with my other tasks that use variations of the same pytest.main() and .create(). 
One other observation is if I run this task first and the Database access error is thrown all the other tasks will fail with the same error.

My working theory is that something about the for loop or if is causing .create() to freak out, but I have absolutely no idea why.

Comment: When you move it to its own function are you running that from the shell or on your Celery worker? It seems like a permission issue which in my mind makes me think there is a settings difference between the two scenarios you are running

Comment: At the moment I run the tasks from the box they are on via shell_plus. by importing them, and then calling them directly for example: [1]: from tasks import run_single_test
[2]: run_single_test('test_name')

Comment: but the error/no error results are in the exact same environment?

Comment: correct. they are in the same env. In this setup I have 4 docker containers the celery tasks live on one box, and they are talking to a psql box. All the tasks are inserting into the same database.

Comment: are the imports the same for the two files? have you implemented this? https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-give-database-access-to-all-my-tests-without-the-django-db-marker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, `pytest.main` does not care about global state left after the test run as it is assumed that the process terminates with the returned exit code after the test run completes. Thus, if you're running code in the same process after `pytest.main` finishes, you have to be cautious about the modifications in the scope. One of them is the database blocker activated by `pytest-django` on django test configuration; it is not deactivated after the test execution finishes. To deactivate, either do it in the code explicitly:

```
import pytest_django

def run_single_test(test_name_or_decorator):
    ...
    pytest.main(['-p', 'no:django','--json-report', test_path])
    pytest_django.plugin._blocking_manager.unblock()

    # database access unblocked, you can run the query now
    test_run_data = TestResults.objects.create(name=report_id, data=report)
```

or add a post-run hook that will do it implicitly, for example:

```
# conftest.py

import pytest_django

def pytest_unconfigure(config):
    pytest_django.plugin._blocking_manager.unblock()
```

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: I would like to understand the original cause of this. Was this directly a result of me including pytest.main() and the .create() in the if statement? At one point I had tried creating a pytest command as a subprocess but that did not address the issue. Was even that not enough to stop the conflict?

Comment: _Was this directly a result of me including pytest.main() and the .create() in the if statement?_ - yes. _At one point I had tried creating a pytest command as a subprocess but that did not address the issue_ - are you sure you didn't put both `pytest` and `create` statements in the subprocess? Invoking `pytest.main` in e.g. a `subprocess.run`, waiting for the exit code and the calling `create` should also be a viable solution.

Comment: Thank you again. I very much appreciate when the help I receive here fixes my issue, but especially in this instance I wanted to understand the cause.